# How to rotate images that are being dynamically loaded into a list view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list view:

```
            <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="invList" ItemSelected="invListSelected" RowHeight="50" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="64"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="64"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="5,5,5,5" HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="{Binding SourceImage}" VerticalOptions="Center" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,3" Text="{Binding Content}" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Medium" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

This list view is being populated using this c# code:

```
 InvStrucSync structureSync = new InvStrucSync();
 structureData = await structureSync.GetStructures(viewModel.CompanyData.company_id);
 foreach (Structure structure in structureData)
 {
    if (structure.archived == "True")
       continue;

    var lt = new ListTemplate(structure.id, structure.name, ImageSource.FromFile("default_image.png"));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(structure.photos))
       if (structure.photos.Length % 4 == 0)
       {
          lt.SourceImage = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(structure.photos)));

          var directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(structure.photos)));
         if (Device.Android == "Android")
         {
            foreach (var directory in directories)
               foreach (var tag in directory.Tags)
                  if (tag.Name == "Orientation")
                  {
                     if (tag.Description == "Top, left side(Horizontal / normal)")
                     {

                     }
                     else if (tag.Description == "Left side, bottom (Rotate 270 CW)")
                     {

                     }
                     else if (tag.Description == "Right side, top (Rotate 90 CW")
                     {
                        //Rotate image
                     }
                  }

               }
            }

            listDisplay.Add(lt);
         }
```

Basically the above code loops through the data pulled from a database then it creates a ListTemplate which is then added to the list display and displayed to the user. I would like to rotate the image in the listview for that particular item I have just created. However, I am not sure as to how to reference the newly created image. Is their a way that I can get the image created and rotate it a certain amount of degrees?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [FFImageLoading plugin](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading). You should be able to do what you want with `Binding` the `Degree`  property on the `RotateTransformation` - you might want/need to use a converter. Check out the `RotateTransformation` [FFImageLoading sample](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/blob/master/samples/ImageLoading.Forms.Sample/Shared/Pages/Transformations/RotateTransformationPage.xaml) to get an idea